# Media Creation Tool Win 10 не видит флешку

Tags: windows, usb

Извините за столь глупый вопрос, но у меня появилась проблема коей ранее небыло. Я неоднократно создавал загрузочную флешку через официальный установщик виндовс.
Но вот в феврале 2019 года(может что-то зависит от даты) мой одноклассник попросил меня переустановить ему виндовс (точнее он переустановит дома с моей помощью по дискорду, в основном требовалось создать загрузочную флешку). Я как всегда зашёл на официальный сайт Майкрософт и скачал media creation tool win 10. Зашёл как всегда принял условия, выбрал версию язык и разрядность, выбрал создать загрузочный носитель (у меня флешка на 16 гиг), но меня не встретила менюшка с выбором носителя, а сразу появилось сообщение о том что на диске C: должно быть более 8 гиг, хоть этот процесс никак не должен был его затрагивать. Я искал ответ на многих форумах но корректного ответа не нашёл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас видимо нет места на диске C:, MCT создаёт большой временный файл. Если не можете освободить то назначьте другое место для временных файлов в переменной окружения TEMP:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]